# Где проходит граница причастного оборота?

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, определить границу причастного оборота!

Наиболее перспективным конструктивным вариантом, обеспечивающим надежную герметизацию места выхода штока из корпуса регулирующих и запорно-регулирующих клапанов, а также другой трубопроводной арматуры с поступательным движением регулирующего органа (,) является сильфонное уплотнение штока.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причастный оборот - это причастие с зависимыми от него словами. Разберемся. Что обеспечивается?***Надежная герметизация места выхода штока из корпуса регулирующих и запорно-регулирующих клапанов, а также другой трубопроводной арматуры с поступательным движением регулирующего органа.*** Следовательно, указанная запятая в скобках нужна, она закрывает причастный оборот. 
Но ваше предложение очень тяжелое. В одном причастном обороте сразу три повтора " регулирующих". Причастный оборот разрывается союзом ''также''. Предложение нужно перестроить.